# Execute php file with javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I want to execute php file in javascript function. Code is as shown below:

```
<a id="cancel" href="./?&amp;_action=list" onclick="javascript:clearRecord();return rcm.command('list','',this,event)">Cancel</a>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var u1='michael';
function clearRecord() {
        $(function() {
            location.href = 'clear.php?h='+u1;
        });
    }
</script>
```

But when I click to cancel button, clear.php not executed. How I should come out from this?

Comment: No "javascript:" prefix in onclick, it expects nothing but Javascript. But you could write that single line into the onclick handler too instead of calling a function that does nothing more than that anyway. I'm not going to mention that you shouldn't have any "onclick" stuff in your HTML in any real project... :-)

Comment: AS Morre says there is not need to have `javascript:` in the onclick attribute. Why don't you move `return rcm.command` to the function `clearRecord`?

Comment: How can this been possible?

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery(?) - if so, here are examples for writing on-click handlers. Remove your entire onclick html-inline code and replace with a proper click handler as shown here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 10):

full & working answer to your question:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        function cancelClicked() {
            // function below will run clear.php?h=michael
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "clear.php" ,
                data: { h: "michael" },
                success : function() { 

                    // here is the code that will run on client side after running clear.php on server

                    // function below reloads current page
                    location.reload();

                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="cancel" href="#" onclick="cancelClicked()">Cancel</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to just execute some php and leave current page to the one generated by this php script. then you got it almost right.
I do not see that you are using jquery - so skip this "$(function(){})" part, and i don't see what u1 is added for but this will work:

```
function clearRecord() { location.href = 'clear.php'; }
```

and this will do the same:

```
<a href="clear.php">Cancel</a>
```

BUT if you want only to run "clear.php" and then reload current page.
One way of doing it can be putting at the end of your "clear.php" file something like:

```
header("Location:/");
```

(it will work only if clear.php does't write anything in response).

But you can do it other ways:
- using AJAX - call clear.php with jQuery.get() and call location.reload() on success;
- using IFRAME - set iframe's location to clear.php and then call window.location.reload();
- using IMG - set img.src to clear.php ...
...and possibly many other ways :)

Comment: This page is another one(com.html) & I want to return on this page. If I use above code, it'd redirect to clear.php

Comment: i see you don't get what states in my answer - i'll give you one more below - don't forget to mark it as usefull