# Trigger php files using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a like button. The php behind it works as it should. But it refreshes the page. Is it possible to write a javascript between the HTML and the PHP? For example: HTML:

```html
<input type="button" id="like_button"><img src="images/like.png"><?php echo $getVideo["likes"];?></button>
```

And when clicking on *that* button, the javascript triggers the file `like_button.php`, which looks like this:

```php
<?php 
require_once "data_inc/database.php";

   $like = new videos();
   $like->likeButton($_GET["id"]);
```

No link out there shows how it would look like, while having OOP php. If someone could provide a javascript, it would help everyone who are currently facing this. How would the javascript look like?
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314978/execute-php-file-with-javascript-function

Answer (score 0):

You should make AJAX call. for example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="get_like()" id="like_button"><img src="images/like.png"><?php echo $getVideo["likes"];?></button>

<script>
    function get_like() {
        fetch('http(s)://<server>/like_button.php', {'method': 'get'})
            .then(data=> {})
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        
    }
</script>
```

You can read more on `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Otherwise you can use any ajax call, for example from jQuery if you like.

For this purpose I would also consider using `<button>` instead of `<input>`

Comment: The code didn't work. I tried this ```$( "#like_form" ).on( "click", function(data) {
  console.log('Form triggered');
  fetch('like_button.php', {'method': 'get'})
            .then(data=> {})
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
     })``` which outputs "Form Triggerd", but doesn't trigger the php file..

Comment: don't you have a <form> somewhere ? did you change <input> to <button> to avoid triggering sending form ?

Comment: With this code only in `<body>` tag and with filled in address it works fine. If you have other code you should post it or modify the answer to suit your needs.